# login failed after url rewrite activation on prestashop

Tags: url, prestashop

I am facing an issue in prestashop since today. Any help will be appreciated.

1) when I activate url rewrite in my shop prestashop, we can not disconnect from a client account.
2) all my old urls in google are not redirected although I have configured "301 redirect to the canonical url" and "enable simplified urls" and "force the update of uRLs to each updating of products. "

Thousands thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the website ?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just an error on my side. everything works fine now. Thanks a lot